# Turtles Get Stuck on Patch if asked to Face Patch

Tags: netlogo

How can I get turtles to directly walk towards a patch? In other components of the model, I direct them toward a specific scent, but I already have them walking towards the food scent in the look-for-food procedure, which is run before changing breed and returning to the nest. Right now, they reach the nest but then wander, and I want them to return directly to the food. I tried repeating the procedure, but that did not direct the leader breed towards the food at all; in fact, all turtles stopped performing the procedure. When I use face, as below, they simply get stuck at the food patch, and never return to the nest at all.

```
ask leaders
  [look-for-food
     fd 1
    return-to-nest
    recruit]
end

to recruit
ask leaders
  [facexy -41 -21
  fd 5] 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the `end` is inside the code block. This can't be the code you are using, it would fail the syntax checker and wouldn't run at all. So you should probably update the code to show what you are actually running.

Regardless, you appear to have a misconception about how NetLogo 'thinks'. Each `tick` or timestep, the leaders do everything inside the code block. Assume there is one leader, it looks for food, then moves forward, then returns to nest to looks for food again, then asks all leaders (in this case itself only) to face a particular patch and then move forward 5 distance units. Instead, the code should be broken up and should contain what the leaders do within one timestep. For example, if they have not yet found food, then you probably want them to look for food and move towards the food. If they have found food, then you may have them returning to the nest.

Have a look at the Ants model in the NetLogo model library. I suggest you work through that model (and probably some of the tutorials listed in the Resources page on the NetLogo site) to fully understand how the model works.